# Перетаскивание объектов Java Android

Tags: java, android, библиотека

Нужно, по нажатию, перетаскивать кнопку с места где она была, на место, где её отпустят. То есть, кнопка следует за пальцем. Подскажите библиотеку, для таких действий. Нужно реализовать это именно библиотекой.

Comment: А зачем именно библиотекой?

Comment: Android drag/drop framework, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop